# Small line appearing when hovering over

Tags: html, css, safari

So I've got a grid of 6 blocks, which will link to subpages. When hovering over these blocks, a small line appears in safari. (I'm not sure, but It looks like pixel jitter or something like that)

A live example here: http://www.scoutsoverijse.be/test/ (you will have to click on 'takken' in the nav bar)

Does anyone have an idea on why that this small line appears? It's kinda annoying...

html:

```
<section id="takken-text" class="takken-section">           
    <div class="square">
        <div class="tak-item">
            <a href="#">Kapoenen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="tak-item">
            <a href="#">Welpen</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    ...  
    <div class="square">
        <div class="tak-item">
            <a href="#">Akabe</a>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</section>
```

css:

```
.takken-section {
    padding: 0px 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 31%;
    padding-bottom: 18%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin: 1% 1.16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tak-item {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    padding: 0;
}

.tak-item > a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.tak-item > a:link, .tak-item > a:visited {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

.tak-item > a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to outline. Add below code in your CSS file.

```
.active > a, a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
    outline: medium none;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the white line still appears when hovering. It doesn't do this in other browsers than safari.